# Fetch balance from Huobi using ccxt

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt, huobi

I'm trying to fetch future account balance on huobi.

This is the code I use:

```
b = ccxt.huobi({
    "apiKey": "API KEY",
    "secret": "SECRET",
    "options": {
        "defaultType": "future"
    },
})
b.fetch_balance()
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
ccxt.base.errors.ExchangeError: huobi {
"status": "error",
"err_code": 4002,
"err_msg": "The merged cross and isolated margin account for USDT-M futures is unavailable.Please complete the query with linear-swap-api/v3/unified_account_info",
"ts": 1695638305262
}
```

I tried to read huobi API docs as well as ccxt docs, but didn't find anything useful.

Can you please help me with figuring out what is the problem and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work you need to switch the account type on exchange.

It is possible to make with ccxt.

1. Connect to huobi with ccxt:

`exchange = ccxt.huobi({...api...secret...})`

2. Run:

`exchange.contractPrivatePostLinearSwapApiV3SwapSwitchAccountType({'account_type': 1})`